# Translating native SQL to Doctrine 2 DQL - Self referencing many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to produce doctrine 2 DQL query based of this native sql query:

```
SELECT f2.follower_id, u.*
            FROM 
                users u,
                user_followers f1
                join user_followers f2 ON (f2.user_id = f1.follower_id AND f2.follower_id != f1.user_id )
            WHERE f1.user_id = :user_id
            AND u.id = f2.follower_id
            AND f2.follower_id NOT IN (
                SELECT follower_id 
                FROM user_followers 
                WHERE user_id = :user_id
            )
            GROUP BY 1
            HAVING count(*) > 1
```

It is based on User Entity which has self referencing many to many relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="following")
 */
private $followers;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="followers", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_followers",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="follower_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $following;
```

I am completely stumped and do not have a slightest idea on how to implement it.
Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your query into two parts. One is to get the follower id's to check NOT IN in the inner query.

Taking the follower id's first,

The next query will be something like this,

```
$fid = $qb1->select('u.follower_id')
           ->from('UserFollowers','u')
           ->where('u.user_id = :ui')
           ->setParameter('ui', $user_id)
```

Then in the next query you need to pass it on where you validate NOT IN. The dql will be something like this.

```
$dql = $qb2->select('f2.follower_id','u')
          ->from('Users','u')
          ->leftJoin('u.following', 'f2', Expr\Join::ON, 'f2.user_id = u.id')
          ->where('u.id = f2.follower_id')
          ->andWhere('f2.follower_id NOT IN :folid')
          ->setParameter('folid', $fid)
          ->groupBy(1)
          ->andHaving($qb2->expr()->count('u'), 0);
```

You can get more information from here :- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: Thanks for helping, but problem is I do not have UserFollowers class, so I can't really do first query like that.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. Isn't UserFollowers Entity in your application?

Comment: No, table user_followers is generated from self referencing relationship. Check annotation on those variables I posted.